# findViewById(R.id.videoView) Returns Null in a Fragment (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, video, nullpointerexception

First of all, I have looked at all other posts relating to this issue, but nothing has resolved the issue.

I am trying to display a video feed within a Fragment, but findViewById(R.id.videoView) always throws back NullPointException errors. I believe I have narrowed down the issue to findViewById returning null or somehow R.id.videoView is null (despite being properly connected to an int).

CameraView.class:

```
public class CameraView extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameraview_layout, container, false);
        playVideo();
        return view;
    }

    public void playVideo(){
        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) new AppCompatActivity().findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Videos\\video.mp4")));
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(myVideoView.getContext()));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();
    }


}
```

cameraview_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="342dp"
        android:layout_height="288dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="208dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am not sure why findViewById still returns null, even after trying to follow the many different posts on here and elsewhere. As far as I am aware, videoView is a valid id. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `new AppCompatActivity()` seriously? **you should never create instance of activity by yourself** you should use findview on `view` inside of `onCreateView` and store result in field in fragment

Answer (score 0):

You should either keep a reference to your view or your binding that you created in onCreateView as a global variable in the fragment and use that to get view objects.

```
public class CameraView extends Fragment {
    View rootView ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameraview_layout, container, false);
        playVideo();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void playVideo(){
        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Videos\\video.mp4")));
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(myVideoView.getContext()));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();
    }


}
```

or

```
public class CameraView extends Fragment {
    CameraviewLayoutBinding binding;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = CameraviewLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        playVideo();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void playVideo(){
        VideoView myVideoView = binding.videoView;
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Videos\\video.mp4")));
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(myVideoView.getContext()));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();
    }


}
```

both of these should work, choose what you like but I prefer the binding one.